# Integrating GPS to my application - Not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, gps

This is my code, i entered this in the `viewDidLoad` method; (This is my view controller)
I am following a tutorial and the source code can be found [here](http://www.vellios.com/2010/08/16/core-location-gps-tutorial/)

```
corelocation = [[CorelocAPI alloc] init];
    corelocation.delegate = self;    
[corelocation.locMgr startUpdatingLocation];


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog (@"Failed !"); // This never gets executed. For more details why this is happening read below

}

- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)newLocation {

    NSLog(@"location - %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",self.lat]);


}
```

In the CorelocAPI i have defined all these;

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if(self != nil) {
        self.locMgr = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease]; // Create new instance of locMgr
        self.locMgr.delegate = self; // Set the delegate as self.
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    if([self.delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(CoreLocationControllerDelegate)]) {  
        [self.delegate locationUpdate:newLocation];
    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if([self.delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(CoreLocationControllerDelegate)]) {  
        [self.delegate locationError:error];
    }
}
```

The problem i am having is when there is an error it executes the `didFailWithError` method in the 
`CorelocAPI` class, and not the `view controllers` `didFailWithError` method. Therefore it never executes the `NSLog` in the `didFailWithError` method of the `viewController` class.

How can i modify my code to make the program execute the `didFailWithError` method of the `viewController` class (when an error occurs) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your view controller error method is wrong, it should be `locationError:(NSError *)error`, not `locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error`

it looks like you're getting delegates mixed up, the view controller is a delegate of the CoreLocAPI object, which is a delegate of its CLLocationManager object

Comment: Even after adding `locationError:(NSError *)error` to my UIViewCOntroller, it still doesn't execute this block when there's an error

Comment: other things i can think of: the didFailWithError is not getting called in the CorelocAPI, or the view controller has not been declared as a delegate so is failing the conformsToProtocol check